# JSON read from sparkcore to python

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, sparkcore

I have searched the web but couldn't find a suitable answer so I will try and ask here.

I am experimenting with a spark core and parsing data through JSON. I have already managed to read the data and print it with the following code:

```
import urllib, json
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/mycore/result?access_token=accesstoken"
response = urllib.urlopen(url);
data = json.loads(response.read())
pprint(data)
```

And now I am trying to print the value I am sending with this code:

```
data["result"]["data1"]
```

I found the above in another topic but I am probably to unexperienced to properly apply it to my own code.

This is what python prints:

```
{u'cmd': u'VarReturn',
 u'coreInfo': {u'connected': True,
           u'deviceID': u'1111111111111111111',
           u'last_app': u'',
           u'last_handshake_at': u'2015-03-09T12:28:20.271Z',
           u'last_heard': u'2015-03-09T12:56:42.780Z'},
 u'name': u'result',
 u'result': u'{"data1":2869}'}
```

the error I get says the following: TypeError: string indices must be integers

I used the example code from this topic:

https://community.spark.io/t/example-logging-and-graphing-data-from-your-spark-core-using-google/2929

I hope I am clear, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print out `data["result"]`. From python print you have provided, the output should be `'{"data1":2869}'`, which is another json object.

Try something like this:

```
import urllib, json
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/mycore/result?access_token=accesstoken"
response = urllib.urlopen(url);
data = json.loads(response.read())
pprint(data)

new_data = json.loads(data["result"])
print new_data["data1"]
```

Comment: Thanks! it works like a charm now!

I am completely new to using JSON so I had no clue that it was a json object within a json object. Is this something that normal to have or not?

Comment: From the link you send, from spark.io tutorial, it seems that it is up to you what you'll pass in results. Another JSON object is fine, just remember to parse it.

Comment: Ok now that I got it working I´ll take a closer look at what I can do with JSON.

Thanks again for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

The contents of data["result"] is a unicode string. The string contains something that looks like a JSON doc / Python dictionary (see the single quotes around the whole construction):

```
>>> data["result"]
u'{"data1":2869}'
```